# Am I reading monk's whirling throw correctly?

Tags: pathfinder-2e-playtest

> ### [image] Whirling Throw Feat 6
>
> **Requirements** You have a creature grabbed or restrained.
>
> ---
>
> You propel your grabbed or restrained foe a great distance. Choose a distance in feet of up to 10 + 5 × your Strength modifier that you want to throw the creature. Attempt an Athletics check with a DC of 5 plus the total distance in feet you’re trying to throw the creature. You take a –2 circumstance penalty to your check for every size the target is larger than you or a +2 circumstance bonus to your check for every size the target is smaller than you.
>
> If you throw the creature, it takes bludgeoning damage equal to your
> Strength modifier plus 1d6 per 10 feet you threw it.
>
> **Success** You throw the creature up to 10 feet.
>
> **Critical Success** You throw the creature the desired distance.
>
> **Failure** You don’t throw the creature.
>
> **Critical Failure** You don’t throw the creature, and it’s no longer
> grabbed or restrained by you.

It seems to me that not only do you increase the DC of the check when you try to throw a creature farther, even if you succeed on the check it only throws it 10 feet instead of the increased distance.

Is this really the correct reading?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Yes, you're reading correctly.

As written, you increase the DC of the throw by trying to throw them further, but a plain success only ever throws them 10'.

So a thrower with 14 Strength could attempt to throw a creature up to 20' (10 + 2*5). Attempting to throw 10' would be an Athletics Check with a DC of 15, where success and critical success would both result in the same conclusion, a creature thrown 10'. Attempting to throw them 20' would be an Athletics Check with a DC of 25, however, where success throws them 10' and critical success throws them 20'.

I'd however note that you get to add your level to your proficiency, so if you're Trained in Athletics, a 10th level Monk would have a +10 to the Athletics roll plus their Strength modifier (more if Expert/Master). So at higher levels you can often throw foes further than you previously could, even if your Strength or proficiency rank don't continue scaling.

Comment: Darn, I was hoping I was reading it wrong.

Answer (score 3):

### Yes, you are correct

This is one of the few abilities that have a **fixed DC** when used against an enemy, instead of using a level-based difficulty or one of the target's saving throws as suggested by the GM chapter. So I suspect that there is a chance this may change before the final version of the rules.

As such, it will scale very nicely, and soon you will be throwing at a minimum of 10 ft even if you roll 2 on the dice. I would just like to point out that a 10th level monk is probably throwing a target at 15 ft minimum by then (10 from proficiency, +4 or +5 from str, +2 from master), and throwing 20 ft without difficulty (7-8 on d20). This isn't a bad feat at all.

Note that the damage is *not* the greatest potential of this ability, but **throwing enemies on hazardous locations**, such as pits, traps, spell areas, forest fires and similar. Moving them into position for allies to catch them on effects is also a pretty good choice considering that this ability only uses two actions (grapple and throw). Forced movements like this have been a *no-no* on first edition, and usually were followed by a phrase clarifying that the target was allowed a second saving throw to avoid the new danger.